# How to use: python warnings.warn()?

Tags: python, warnings

This is my code that I wrote:

```
#usr/bin/python3
import warnings

def tt():

    warnings.warn("123")

    return 10

x = tt()

print(x)
```

It prints:

```
test.py:5: UserWarning: 123

warnings.warn("123")

10
```

I want it to only print:

```
test.py:5: UserWarning: 123
10
```

Without `warnings.warn("123")`.

What should I do?

Answer (score 4):

You can replace the function used to format the messages; for example:

```
def warning_on_one_line(message, category, filename, lineno, file=None, line=None):
        return '%s:%s: %s:%s\n' % (filename, lineno, category.__name__, message)

warnings.formatwarning = warning_on_one_line
```

[Python Module of the week article](https://pymotw.com/2/warnings/)

Answer (score 1):

```
import warnings
# import pdb

def format_Warning(message, category, filename, lineno, line=''):
    return str(filename) + ':' + str(lineno) + ': ' + category.__name__ + ': ' +str(message) + '\n'

warnings.formatwarning = format_Warning

def tt():

    warnings.warn("123")

    return 10

x = tt()

print(x)
```

Hope it helps!